# I need explanation on what RelayCommand is

Tags: windows-phone-8

I was reading a .net source code on MVVM in windows 8 development. I saw some funny objects Called RelayCommand. I tried to read up on it. But I still dont understand what RelayCommand is about. Any body help with a simple explanation of what it is and why I need to use it.

Thanks alot

Comment: It is MVVM plumbing, used to relay a command to a nested class inside the view model.  Nesting keeps the view model from exploding in size.  Read more about MVVM command routing in many articles, like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try to do my best to explain clearly.

In XAML and MVVM you have some properties called Commands in controls descending from ButtonBase. this Command property allows you to bind (using data binding `{Binding propertyname}`) to a property in your viewmodel of a type who implements the ICommand interface. Later, the button can execute that "Command" when the user makes click.

if you implements the ICommand interface in a class, call it HelloCommand for example, you have a CanExecute and Execute methods, CanExecute returns a bool and is used to evaluate if the command can be executed. Execute is the code the command is going to execute when the user clicks the button.

This means, for each button you need to create a class implementing ICommand. RelayCommand is a class who implements ICommand and allows you to pass as parameters in the constructor the methods to execute in the CanExecute and Execute ICommand methods. This way you don't need to implement over and over the ICommand interface.

Hope is clear enought...